# Cannot Set SonarQube Quality Profile on Project

Tags: sonarqube

We have defined our own custom Quality Profiles in SonarQube (version 6.4) and set them as default:

```
Java - Acme Java Profile
Javascript - Acme Javascript Profile
CSS - Acme CSS Profile
XML - Acme XML Profile
```

For a particular project, we selected these profiles via Administration->Quality Profiles.

On the project page, though, it only shows two profiles (Java and XML) and they are both set to Sonar way. The project definitely has Javascript and CSS files and they are not be excluded.

There is no sonar.properties or sonar-project.properties file for this project. We have tried to use those and they don't make a difference.

Comment: Project Page shows profiles used during last analysis (which is what the data shown on that page relates to), so I suggest you rerun an analysis, and if doubts remain then review and share: debug analysis logs + screenshot of that homepage.

Comment: Thank you. We have run the analysis multiple times since making the changes and it still just shows the two Sonar way profiles. Are the analysis logs available via the UI somewhere or just on the server?

Comment: I found an error in either the ce.log or the es.log about not recognizing "95%" in the Quality Gate. We changed that to "95" and reran the analysis. It now shows our Quality Profiles, but still only two of them: Java and XML. How can I get it to recognize the Javascript and CSS profiles?

Comment: The analysis logs are the output of the Scanner executed in your CI (where the code is checked out and analysed), the _debug_ logs there (_sonar.verbose=true_) will give you hints about which files are analyzed and which profiles are used accordingly.